# javascript - wrap iframe tags around <td> cell content value

Tags: javascript, iframe, html-table

I have a `<td>` tag with a url inside and I'd like to put `<iframe>` around the url such that the url is displayed in an iframe like `<iframe src='www.youtube.com'>youtube</iframe>`

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<td class='vid'>https://www.youtube.com/</td>

<button onclick="myFunction()">iframe</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("td.vid");
  x.outerHTML = "<iframe src=" + x.textContent + "></iframe>";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

initially, the console kept returning a nodeList with length 0. For some reason, the console is not returning anymore messages after some more testing ( I am using Edge).

How can I properly grab the innertext/textcontent of the td and put iframes around it?

Comment: Do you have multiple "td.vid" elements? Because you are getting an array with querySelectorAll, if its only one then you can just use querySelector to find the first match.

Comment: @user1738483, it's not set in stone, it is likely there will be multiple td.vid elements. My javascript can't seem to target them correctly though

Comment: Then you'll have to loop through all the elements with the class you are targeting. Right now, 'x' is an HTMLCollection so to aim for it's first element, you'd have to do x[0] for example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to point out. In your specific example listed here, you cant get the element data because the 'td' element is not attached to a table. May be different in your actual code.

Regarding the iframe wrapper, its easier to me if you just create an iframe element, change the src of the element and the APPEND it to the 'td' element. You can use JS to remove the text as well if you want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table>
  <td class='vid'>https://www.youtube.com/</td>
</table>


<button onclick="myFunction()">iframe</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("vid");
  var xElm = x[0]
  let frame = document.createElement('iframe');
  frame.src = xElm.innerHTML;
//now remove the text
  xElm.innerHTML = "";
//now attache the iframe.
  xElm.append(frame);
}
</script>

</body>
</html> 
``
```

Answer (score 1):

a `td` element must be put inside a `table` element for it to work.

Check this example.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.querySelector(".vid");
  x.outerHTML = "<iframe src=" + x.textContent + "></iframe>";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <table>
    <td class='vid'>https://www.youtube.com/</td>
  <table>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">iframe</button>
</body>
</html>
```